# SSDT OPENJSON Incorrect warning message

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

The following function gives
Warning in SSDT 14.0.60923.0
SQL71502: Function: [dbo].[fn_CheckPolicy] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Users].[d] incorrectly in Visual Studio 2015.

Is there a way around this or is it a bug in SSDT?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CheckPolicy] (@NameIdentifier nvarchar(128),
                                        @Id             uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE (
  [Id]  uniqueidentifier,
  [Acl] int )
AS
  BEGIN
      WITH cte
           AS (SELECT 1                                 AS [Level],
                      JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.id')     AS 'Id',
                      JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.acl')    AS 'acl',
                      JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.type')   AS 'type',
                      JSON_QUERY(d.[value], '$.s')      AS 'data'
               FROM   [dbo].[Users] u
                      CROSS apply OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(u.[Policy], '$.c')) d
               WHERE  u.[NameIdentifier] = @nameIdentifier
               UNION ALL
               SELECT [Level] + 1,
                      ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.id'), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
                      JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.acl'),
                      JSON_VALUE(d.[value], '$.type')        'type',
                      JSON_QUERY(d.[value], '$.a')           'data'
               FROM   cte
                      CROSS apply OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY([data], '$')) d)
      INSERT INTO @returnTable
      SELECT [Id],
             CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, [Acl], 1))
      FROM   cte
      WHERE  [Id] = @id

      IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO @returntable
                    ([Id],[Acl])
        VALUES      (@id,'0xff')

      RETURN
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug with the handling of OPENJSON in SSDT.  There were some bug fixes in this area in recent versions of SSDT, but it appears that this is another issue.  Could you please file a Connect bug for this at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)"?  Thank you!